# Single custom terminal command to open multiple windows with different things inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I find myself running the same terminal commands when I turn on the laptop. I press ctrl+alt+t to open a new terminal window. (I am a beginner working with RoR on Ubuntu 12.04)

1. I open new terminal window and navigate to Rails folder and run **vim**
2. I open another terminal window, navigate to Rails folder and run
   '**bundle exec guard**'
3. I open another window, and run **rails console**
4. I open another window with **rails server** running on it
5. I open another window with **IRSSI** (IRC client on it)

How to perform these actions with single terminal command? I guess a custom script is required, but I don't know how to write it or where to put it... Also, if possible, I'd like to open them in a full screen terminal windows

Comment: @DennisWilliamson embarrased to say but I don't know. How to find out? It's basically the default terminal in Ubuntu, the one wich opens with the shortcut ctrl+alt+t, and the one that is on that left hand side menu on desktop

Comment: You're using probably `gnome-terminal`. Which is shipped default by ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tmux` for these kind of staff. For example the example below will create 5 windows(which are tabs), each named with the first parametr after `-n` and then executed.

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-session -d -s hawkhost

tmux new-window -t hawkhost:1 -n 'vim' 'vim'
tmux new-window -t hawkhost:2 -n 'bundle' 'bundle exec guard'
tmux new-window -t hawkhost:3 -n 'rails1' 'rails console'
tmux new-window -t hawkhost:4 -n 'rails2' 'rails server'
tmux new-window -t hawkhost:5 -n 'irc' 'irsii'

tmux select-window -t hawkhost:1
tmux -2 attach-session -t hawkhost
```

Look here for more information about this:

http://blog.hawkhost.com/2010/07/02/tmux-%E2%80%93-the-terminal-multiplexer-part-2/#tmux-shell-scripting

In tmux `panes` are arbitary windows, and `windows` are actually tabs.

Comment: Here with tabs i mean the tabs that are created inside tmux. I think the best way is to learn tmux, because you have then one single UX (in our example tmux) which you can use it everywhere. For example in Konsole, Gnome-Terminal, urxvt I always have tmux open, therefore all keybindings and behaviours are the same on all different terminals. This makes lots of things easier for you.

Comment: thanks, will definetly check it out! will report back with impressions and wait if someone else offers their answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You want a screen multiplexer such as [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: wich will allow me to open them in different tabs, right? I'd prefer without it, but if you know how to achieve what I asked with screen multiplexer, than go ahead :)